# How can I access semi-sparse data efficiently in java?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

So I'm working with a problem where I am parsing a large text file into data - each row of the file being represented by a `Node` object with several data fields.

During program execution, these objects will be accessed many times according to their `int id` field (specified in the text document).

If every `id` was present, I would simply store them as a `Node[]` array, and wanting to access the node with `id` x, I would simply use `nodeArray[x]`.

However, the data is such that most values of `id` don't exist. For my current data set, only about 40-50% of the `id`'s between 0 and the largest `id`, `ID_MAX` in the set are present in the set.

The way I see it, I have two options:

Use a large `Node[]` with many unfilled entries, as in

```
Node[] nodeArray = new Node[ID_MAX];

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Node n = ... // parse line of text into Node object
    nodeArray[n.getID()] = n;
end
br.close();
```

This would make accessing the node with a certain id trivial, but uses a lot of extra space in cases where the data set is large.

Another option is to use a smaller `Node[]` array and using a sparse `int[]` array for indexing:

```
Node[] nodeArray = new Node[NUM_ROWS];
int[] indexArray = new Int[ID_MAX];

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
int i = 0;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Node n = ... // parse line of text into Node object
    nodeArray[i] = n;
    indexArray[n.id] = i;
    i++;
}
```

Are any of the two in general better than the other or does it depend on size and sparsity of the data?
Is there another way I haven't considered that is better than any of the two?

Comment: you can use Map<Integer, Node>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've described here you can use `HashMap<Integer, Node>` or `HashMap<Long, Node>` depending on the range of ids you have.

Depending on your other requirements `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap` might be alternatives (`LinkedHashMap` if you need to iterate over the nodes in the order that they were inserted and `TreeMap` if you need them to be sorted by some certain criteria).

Comment: *if you need the nodes to be in the order that they are inserted* -- You don't really know how they *are*. I'd rather say "if you need to iterate on the nodes in the order they are inserted" (if you need to iterate on the nodes at all, by the way, which is not a standard use case for a map). Other than that, it's exactly what I was about to answer, you beat me to it ;-)

Comment: You can also add that the map removes the constraint of knowing the `ID_MAX`.

Comment: @Joffrey You're right. I've updated my answer to clarify on `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A map seems very similar to my second proposed solution (albeit without the null values in the `int[]` array). Is there significant overhead with using a map? 
As a side note; nodes will not be iterated through in the order of insertion. In general, "nearby" nodes will be accessed more often than far away ones, but there is no fixed pattern.

Comment: For pretty much any application, the overhead of any of the implementations of Map will not be an issue at all. I strongly recommend choosing standard library solutions for things like this. It tends to save a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: I see, thank you. When choosing a type of map, is there anything special I should keep in mind considering the nodes will be inserted in order of increasing keys (`id`)? I seem to remember something about depth of search trees increasing rapidly when stuff appears in a non-random order.

Comment: HashMap has best performance on insert/update/delete. TreeMap is balanced, so inserting sequential ids won't be a problem however it's not as fast as HashMap.